# Change stream not triggering with specific pipeline in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a project where I need to watch for changes in MongoDB documents for groups that a user manages. I'm using change streams in MongoDB to accomplish this. However, I'm facing an issue where the change stream is not triggering when I use a specific pipeline to match documents based on the manager's user ID. I'd like to understand why the change stream is not working as expected and how to fix it.

```
    public ManagerGroupWatch = (user_id: string) => {
      const pipeline = [{ $match: { 'manager.user_id': user_id } }];
      const changeStream = GroupModel.watch(pipeline);
      changeStream.on('change', (change) => {
          // Handle the change event
          console.log('Change:', change);
       });

    }
```

Document example:

```
_id: 'TEST'
name: "test"
entry_coins: 100
uuid: "**********"
group_created: 2023-05-15T11:41:39.369+00:00
participants: Array
tournament: Object
manager: {user_id:'some_id', name:'test'}
current_match: Object
total_amount_win: 300
picture: ""
slug: "test-test"
history_matches: Array
requestsJoins: Array
__v: 4
```

The issue I'm facing is that the change stream is not triggering when I use the pipeline to match documents based on the manager's user ID. However, if I remove the pipeline and watch for all documents, the change stream works fine. I've verified that the documents indeed have the correct manager's user ID. I'm not sure why the change stream is not working with the specific pipeline.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue with the change stream not triggering when using a specific pipeline to match documents based on the manager's user ID, you can make the following changes to your code:

```
public ManagerGroupWatch = (user_id: string) => {
  const pipeline = [{ $match: { 'fullDocument.manager.user_id': user_id } }];
  const changeStream = GroupModel.watch(pipeline, { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' });
  changeStream.on('change', (change) => {
    // Handle the change event
    console.log('Change:', change);
  });
}
```

The key change is in the pipeline where you need to match against the fullDocument.manager.user_id field instead of just manager.user_id. This ensures that the change stream considers the complete document during the matching process.

Additionally, you need to pass **{ fullDocument: 'updateLookup' }** as the second argument to the watch method. This configuration option tells the change stream to return the most current version of the updated document instead of just the delta of fields.

With these changes, the change stream should now trigger correctly based on the pipeline matching the manager's user ID.